# python fuction finding root( or zero) with minimum distance from real root epsilon

Tags: python, function, zero, epsilon

So its and exercises for python i am totally stuck! you have a random Function in [a,b] you already know that the a is negative and b is positive and it has only ONE root. The *true root* is : -0.94564927392359 and you have to make a
def that will find the root( or zero ) that will be closest to the true root with minimum difference *eps*.The *eps* is 1e-8 or 1e-6.Note that we don't know the *true root*, before was an example to understand what the number we are looking for is about. Also we are given the above :

```
import math

def fnc(x):
    """ This the function in which root we are looking for """
    global a, b, eps
    if not hasattr(fnc, "counter"):
        fnc.counter = 0
        fnc.maxtimes = (int)(0.1+math.ceil(math.log((b-a)/eps, 2.0)+2))
    if fnc.counter<fnc.maxtimes:
        fnc.counter += 1
        return x*x*x-x-0.1 
    else:
        return 0.0 ##
```

WE have to start with this :

```
def root(f, a, b, eps):
```

(sorry for my English )

Comment: I don't think this is possible without some additional condition (e.g., [[Lipschitz Continuity]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity).

Comment: @AmiTavory I believe, that OP has posted homework from a basic numerical analysis course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple bisect:

```
from __future__ import division
import math

def func(x):
    return x*x*x-x-0.1

def sign(n):
    try:
        return n/abs(n)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def root(f, a, b, eps=1e-6):
    f_a = f(a)
    if abs(f_a) < eps:
        return a
    f_b = f(b)
    if abs(f_b) < eps:
        return b

    half = (b+a)/2
    f_half = f(half)

    if sign(f_half) != sign(f_a):
        return root(f, a, half, eps)
    else:
        return root(f, half, b, eps)

print root(func, -1.5, -0.5, 1e-8)  # -0.945649273694
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following heuristic of iteratively slicing intervals into 2 equals and then choosing the admissible half is suitable for you.

```
def root(fnc, a, b, eps = 1e-8, maxtimes = None):
    if maxtimes == None: maxtimes = (int)(0.1+math.ceil(math.log((b-a)/eps, 2.0)+2))
    for counter in xrange(maxtimes+1) : # a was assumed negative and b positive
        if fnc(a) > -eps : return a, -fnc(a)
        if fnc(b) < eps : return b, fnc(b)
        new_bound = (a + b)/2.0
        print a, b, new_bound
        if fnc(new_bound) < 0 : a = new_bound
        else : b = new_bound
    return new_bound, min(-fnc(a),fnc(b))
```

and then

```
fnc = lambda x : x**3-x-0.1
result = root(fnc, 0, 2, 1e-6)
print "root = ", result[0], "error = ", result[1]
```